# Does a HttpHead request trigger any scripts on the page?

Tags: session, cookies, scripting, google-analytics, http-head

The title pretty much says it all. I'm working on an android project currently that sends a HttpHead request and verifies which status code is sent back. There are certain sections of the website I am accessing that require session data and if you don't have an active session it will redirect you (status 302) to the login page otherwise it will just go to the requested page (200). So that's my quick and dirty way of telling whether the session cookies I have are valid without downloading a whole page worth of data. I'm just wondering whether this will effect things like Google Analytic tracking data for the website or not so as not to produce false page views for them.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The HTTP spec tells us about HEAD requests:](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4)

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.

If there's no message body, how could there be any scripts (Google Analytics or otherwise) to trigger? *There is literally no response but the HTTP response headers.*